# "...three years in." What does it mean when placing 'in' at the end of a sentence?

Tags: grammar, parts-of-speech

I read on Gabriel Weinberg's [recent blog](http://www.gabrielweinberg.com/blog/2013/05/on-the-cusp-of-something-big.html):

> "Startups are a long-term game. My best advice is to treat entrepreneurship as a career path, but it is easier said than done absent some amount of success. For me, I had a taste of it three years in and some real success six years in."

How does the grammar of ***in*** work here:
*I had a taste of it three years **in** and some real success six years **in***.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is the adverbial use of *in* to refer to a distance in a particular direction. In this case it is a distance in time, measured from the time that Gabriel Weinberg started his entrepreneurial career, so somewhat metaphorical.

> in (adverb) 2. to or toward a certain place or direction: "he flies in today", "they live ten miles in". [[yourdictionary.com](http://www.yourdictionary.com/in)]

Comment: To be read as "inwards of (point-in-space/ point-in-time)"? "I had a taste of it **in the past under (within the last)** three years and some real success **in the past under (within the last)** six years." Right?

Comment: @Kris- I'm not sure I understand your phrase with *under* in it.  In any event it's to be read as: *I had a taste of success after spending three years on the project, and some real success six years after starting the project.*  I don't believe it means during the first 3 years, but rather, at the 3-year mark.

Comment: I have to agree with Jim.  @Kris, your comment only muddies the water.  **Under** has nothing to do with the adverbial 'in' in this context.  Instead, to say something happened **3 years in** is the same as to say it happened **3 years into the project** (or as Jim rightly states **after 3 years**).  Thus, the **in** in the OP context has the same meaning as **into**, only **into** is used when there is an object, and **in** is used when there is not.

Comment: @Darling, Take your time, my comment was a question to the answerer and we *need* to wait for a response. Even otherwise, you could substantiate your argument if you had any.

Comment: @ MετάEd: There's some confusion in the comments here. Maybe you should edit to clarify that in OP's construction, the starting point for that "temporal distance" is *the time when the speaker first became an entrepreneur*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Good idea. Did.